# Permission changes when copying bundle in OSX

Tags: macos, filesystems, file-permissions

I have an bundle directory with full permissions (777) (includeing subdirectories)

whenever I copy it to another directory using cp -r I see that it loses some of its permissions.

What is the cause of that and how can I move this bundle while keeping its permissions intact?

I have a Lion version.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-p` flag:

```
cp -Rp whatever whereever
```

From the `cp` manpage:

> ```
> Cause cp to preserve the following attributes of each source file
> in the copy: modification time, access time, file flags, file mode,
> user ID, and group ID, as allowed by permissions.  Access Control
> Lists (ACLs) and Extended Attributes (EAs), including resource
> forks, will also be preserved.
>
> If the user ID and group ID cannot be preserved, no error message
> is displayed and the exit value is not altered.
> If the source file has its set-user-ID bit on and the user ID can-
> not be preserved, the set-user-ID bit is not preserved in the
> copy's permissions.  If the source file has its set-group-ID bit on
> and the group ID cannot be preserved, the set-group-ID bit is not
> preserved in the copy's permissions.  If the source file has both
> its set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits on, and either the user ID or
> group ID cannot be preserved, neither the set-user-ID nor set-
> group-ID bits are preserved in the copy's permissions.
> ```

Comment: @kambi: Also note the use of `-R` rather than `-r` in @trojanfoe's answer. '-r' is arguably broken but retained for backward compatibility. See the bottom of the man page: "Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's."

Comment: Actually the easiest option to use is `-a` which is the same as `-pPR` .